# datagridview population in csharp not working

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagrid

I'm new to c# and have written the following codes :

```
 public partial class MyUserControl1: MyUserControl
    {
        private DataTable dataset;

        public DataGridView datagrid
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public MyUserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            datagrid = new DataGridView();
        }
    }
```

then made a connection to sql and retrieved all data to "dataset", by a loop populated datagrid like this :

```
this.datagrid.Rows.Add(dataset.Rows[i].ItemArray);
```

Now I want to bind "datagrid" to a datagridview in windows form like this

```
datagridview1.datasource = datagrid;
```

but its not working ,where is the problem ?!

Comment: I used "dataset" which is a datatable to retrieve all rows in database
then made a "datagrid" object and populated it using "dataset"
now I want to view if I've correctly populated it or not, so made a DataGridView and want to see "datagrid" contents

Comment: _Doesn't work_ is __not a helpful__ problem description! Does it show? I.e. do you ever add it to the Controls of the UC?? OR does it show no data? Also: You have an uncanny tendency to pick confusing names. DataSet != DataTable. DataGrid != DataGridView

Comment: If I bind "dataset" to the DataGridView1 It works and DB content is shown
but when I try to bind "datagrid" to DataGridView1 its not showing anything

Comment: because your "datagrid" is `datagridview` not `dataset`. You should continue with your old "dataset".

Comment: how can I see "datagrid" content ? It's populated by certain rows of "dataset"

Answer (score 0):

Did it with

```
this.Controls.Add (datagrid);
```

Thanks @TaW for pointing to it